# Add a group of attributes to all products

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, folder

I created a new folder of attributes to a product category, and its working fine. There is a way to add this folder of attributes to all products categories automatically? Or should i add one by one?

Comment: what u mean by `new folder of attributes`

Comment: like this: http://imgur.com/tMs0xka

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the new attributes set to existing products, only to new ones.
The only way would be do change them directly in the database. I would recommand you to find an experienced developer for that.